# Using primary keys best practice

Tags: security, web, web-applications

I'm making a simple blog, each post has an `Id` (nothing new), my concern is their is a problem by letting primary keys simple integer. I see some people making their primary keys in more complex format, I want to know because I'm using ids as a hidden attribute in my forms, and in URLs, is that a security problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use proper access control. The site you are currently viewing is exposing its keys.

Spring Security is an example of existing software, with their ACL implementation.